# using a joins with a has_many relationship rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I have a Trainer model which has a has_many relationship with Pokemon. Inside the Pokemon model, there is a trainer_id field and a species field. I would like to retrieve all Trainer records that have a Pokemon with a species of 'Mew' and another Pokemon with a species of 'Arcanine'.

My attempt that doesn't work:

```
Trainer.joins(:pokemon).where(:pokemon => {:species => 'Mew', :species => 'Arcanine' })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
Trainer.joins(:pokemon).where("pokemons.species in ('Mew', 'Arcanine')")
```

I guess the problem with your query `Trainer.joins(:pokemon).where(:pokemon => {:species => 'Mew', :species => 'Arcanine' })` is it's doing an `and` instead of or.  Another syntax if you want `in` is the following:

```
Trainer.joins(:pokemon).where(:pokemon => {:species => ['Mew', 'Arcanine'] })
```

**Update:**

If you want and option then please try the following:

```
Trainer.joins(:pokemon).where("pokemons.species = 'Mew' and pokemons.species = 'Arcanine'")
```

Comment: That is returning trainers if they have one or the other or both. I need to just find the ones that have both.

Comment: I figured it out. Apparently i was looking for numbers and they weren't supposed to be in quotes. Your second would have worked with strings, such as i have in my example. Thank ya mate. May your sword stay sharp and your steed be quick.